# return type for std::search()

Tags: c++, search, stl

I am trying to test an example of `search()` from Stroustup's book.

```
string quote("why waste time learning, when ignorance is instantaneous?");

bool in_quote(const string& s){
    char* p = search(quote.begin(), quote.end(), s.begin(), s.end());
    return p != quote.end();
}

void test(){
    bool b1 = in_quote("learning"); // b1=true
    bool b2 = in_quote("lemming"); // b2=false
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'char *'
```

It looks like the return type is not right. I also tried `string::iterator`, and got the same error. So, what should be the right type, is it supposed to be the iterator type of the container? Thanks

Comment: If you have C++11, use `auto`.  But it looks like it should be `std::string::iterator`.  What's the message when you try that one?  It should be a different message.

Comment: @ubbdd Iterator is **not** a pointer.

Comment: Open the "Output" window to see the _full_ messages by the way.  It should be telling you the type of `_Elem` there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the following

```
bool in_quote(const string& s){
  string::iterator p = search(quote.begin(), quote.end(), s.begin(), s.end());
  return p != quote.end();
}
```

And it did compile without error ...

Comment: I just found I corrected a typo when copying the code. string::iterator should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

How about simply not caring about the return type? :)

```
bool in_quote(const string& s){
    return search(quote.begin(), quote.end(), s.begin(), s.end()) != quote.end();
}
```

Comment: Good pragmatic answer, but the question is more about why the code sample from the definitive reference book does not work.

Comment: It's quite possible that the error was corrected in later editions. I don't have the book, but Google has it: http://books.google.com/books?id=Bk4iAQAAIAAJ&q=%22why+waste+time+learning,+when+ignorance+is+instantaneous%22&dq=%22why+waste+time+learning,+when+ignorance+is+instantaneous%22&hl=en&ei=30S0ToSxKc30sQKQqqT7Aw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAQ

Comment: @Mark: It appears to be from the link :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a `const string`, so it must be a `const_iterator`:

```
string::const_iterator p = search(quote.begin(), quote.end(), s.begin(), s.end());
```

Comment: I don't think so: The return type of `search` is the same as the first two arguments (it's an itereator into `quote` after all). And `quote` is not const ...

Comment: What are the actual rules? The search string is `const` but the string being searched is not.

Comment: @MartinStettner: seems you're right. But I have good reasons to assume the code given in question is not the exact code that didn't work.

Comment: @MarkRansom You get an iterator into the string being searched (the position, where the search string is found...). Since the string being searched is non-const, the return value is a non-const iterator too ...

Comment: @MartinStettner, that makes total sense, and agrees with the Microsoft documentation once I looked it up. I hadn't seen your comment before I posted mine, mine was directed at ybungalobill.

Answer (score 1):

Early implementations of `string` could easily have used `char*` as their iterator type, allowing this incorrect code snippet to compile properly. Most modern implementations of `string::iterator` have a proper class type and would not be convertible to `char*`.

The signature for [`std::search` is](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/):

```
template <class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2>
   ForwardIterator1 search ( ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
                             ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator2 last2 );
```

As you can see, the return type is the same as the type of the first two iterators passed to the function. In your case `string::iterator` should have worked, unless there is some part of the code you did not show us that made `quote` `const` in which case you could use `string::const_iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Per [SGI documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/search.html), the form of `search` you are using has the signature:

```
template <class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2>
ForwardIterator1 search(ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
                        ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator2 last2);
```

Since your `FowardIterator1` type is `std::string::iterator`, your return type must be `std::string::iterator` as well.